# Should all fetching be done inside getStaticProps in NextJS?

Tags: next.js

In NextJS in order to utilize **static site generation**, I need to perform all network requests inside `getStaticProps`.

I've removed all the `fetch` calls in my React app and moved them inside `getStaticProps`, but how do I deal with requests to show data sorted/filtered by a criteria? The data is too long to be sorted client side.

Do I need to add another path (with `getStaticPaths`) to represent the new sorted permutation?

e.g. `example.com/products/?sort=asc&sort_by=price`

And then read them inside `getStaticProps` as parameters and then fetch the data?

Won't this generate too many permutations? But otherwise how do I pass the **sort** parameter to `getStaticProps` for the querying?

How about filtering by price range? This would be an infinite number of permutations. And how do I put these infinite permutations inside `getStaticPaths`?

Comment: Statically generate the page with `getStaticProps` on the server, then apply any filtering/sorting logic when needed on the client-side.

Answer (score 1):

I think this line is causing you to have some confusion:

> In NextJS in order to utilize static site generation, I need to perform all network requests inside getStaticProps.

This is not quite true. Next.js still uses static site generation even if you have network requests inside of your code. But `getStaticProps` is for data that won't be changing, such as blog posts and generating pages based of those blog items. In your example I'm assuming your trying to use `getStaticProps` for you `/products` URL which is not a good use case because [getStaticProps only runs when you build the application](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props), not every time someone queries it.

So then I would use [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) which uses server side rendering, or I would just [fetch the data inside of your React code.](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/client-side) I would say based off of your issues listed above that you should just fetch the data inside of your React code. Next.js will still render a static html page for this, just the base state would have your loading indicator, and then once your products are fetched based off of your criteria then it would display your products.

For more information on fetching data with Next.js I would look [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching).

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass query params to `getStaticProps` so this whole idea won't work anyway. But if theoretically you could then yes, you would need to make all the permutations manually which is not very feasible.

So if you want to have server-side render on those pages then you need to use `getServerSideProps`, it is your only option if you are using query params.

Other solution would be to render core of the page statically (with `getStaticProps`) but load the data on the client.